# Flip and shift multi-column data to the left in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's an Employee - Supervisor mapping data.

I'd like to flip and then shift whole column to left. Only data should be shifted to the left 1 time and the columns should be fixed. Could you tell me how can I do this?

Input: Bottom - Up approach

| Emp_ID | Sup_1 ID | Sup_2 ID | Sup_3 ID | Sup_4 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 234 | 456 | 678 | 789 |
| 234 | 456 | 678 | 789 | NaN |
| 456 | 678 | 789 | NaN | NaN |
| 678 | 789 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 789 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Output: Top - Down approach

| Emp_ID | Sup_1 ID | Sup_2 ID | Sup_3 ID | Sup_4 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 789 | 678 | 456 | 234 |
| 234 | 789 | 678 | 456 | NaN |
| 456 | 789 | 678 | NaN | NaN |
| 678 | 789 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 789 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Appreciate any kind of assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy-fliplr):

```
# Get numpy structure
x = df.loc[:, 'Sup_1 ID':].to_numpy()
# flip left to right
a = np.fliplr(x)
# Overwrite not NaN values in x with not NaN in a
x[~np.isnan(x)] = a[~np.isnan(a)]
# Update DataFrame
df.loc[:, 'Sup_1 ID':] = x
```

`df`:

```
   Emp_ID  Sup_1 ID  Sup_2 ID  Sup_3 ID  Sup_4 ID
0     123     789.0     678.0     456.0     234.0
1     234     789.0     678.0     456.0       NaN
2     456     789.0     678.0       NaN       NaN
3     678     789.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
4     789       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

---

DataFrame Constructor and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Emp_ID': [123, 234, 456, 678, 789],
    'Sup_1 ID': [234.0, 456.0, 678.0, 789.0, np.nan],
    'Sup_2 ID': [456.0, 678.0, 789.0, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Sup_3 ID': [678.0, 789.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Sup_4 ID': [789.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case try `np.roll`

```
df = df.set_index('Emp_ID')

out = df.apply(lambda x : np.roll(x[x.notnull()].values,1)).apply(pd.Series)
0      1      2      3
Sup_1 ID  789.0  234.0  456.0  678.0
Sup_2 ID  789.0  456.0  678.0    NaN
Sup_3 ID  789.0  678.0    NaN    NaN
Sup_4 ID  789.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
out.columns = df.columns
```